# How to keep a subsetted value for calculating mean

Tags: r

I am currently learning R and I have to solve an Issue were I have to extract values from a data set which are from a specific month and from this values I should calculate the mean Temp.

I did it like that:

data[data$X..Month.. == 6,]

mean(data$X..Temp.., na.rm=TRUE)

It gave me the mean value but without taking my first statement into consideration. 
What do I need to do that both statements are taken into consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just get the mean for month 6:

```
mean(df$temp[df$mon=="Jun"], na.rm=T)
```

You were nearly there but didn't assign your subset to a value, if you had:

```
x = data[data$X..Month.. == 6,]
mean(x$X..Temp.., na.rm=TRUE)
```

that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this using tapply, which will give you the mean for all your subsets, e.g.

dummy data

```
df = data.frame(mon=rep(month.abb, times=10)
```

calculate mean for all months

```
tapply(df$temp, df$mon, mean, na.rm=T)
```